# How can I generate a cryptographically secure random integer within a range?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, random, cryptography

I have to generate a uniform, secure random integer within a given range for a program that generates passwords. Right now I use this:

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] rand = new byte[4];
rng.GetBytes(rand);
int i = BitConverter.ToUInt16(rand, 0);
int result = i%max;   // max is the range's upper bound (the lower is 0)
```

Is this method safe to use for cryptographic purposes? If not, how should I do it?

Comment: I notice that you're generating a 4-byte random sequence, but then converting that to a 2-byte integer (`ushort` / `UInt16`).  Perhaps generate either a 2-byte sequence or convert the 4-byte sequence to `uint` / `UInt32`.  I'm not sure whether the modulo affects cryptographic security in this instance.

Comment: This post seems to indicate that what you're doing is pretty good:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range?rq=1.  Or follow this post to create a cryptographically secure `double` between 0 and 1, and then multiply the result by your upper max?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854438/how-to-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-double-between-0-and-1?rq=1

Comment: Modulo doesn't lead to cryptographically secure random numbers. There are many examples over on [crypto.se]. This is the one I found quickly: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22767/13022

Comment: I posted an asnwer, but I realised that I was not giving any help. So I deleted it, Im sorry.

Comment: @afonte no problem. I began to read your answer, then for some reason refreshed the page, and was surprised to see that it was gone.

Comment: I think I posted a better answer now :)

Comment: @wablab Double and secure don't go together well, rounding issues will make it almost 100% sure that the result is biased, even ever so slightly (but ever so slightly is *very* dangerous when it comes to cryptography.

Comment: See also https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/ -- the comments have some good links to related discussions.

Comment: @YdobEmos After a bit of work the answer is cleaner according to your question. If your consider it helped you please accept that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can have a look at the CryptoRandom class taken from *[niik/CryptoRandom.cs](https://gist.github.com/1017834)* which is the *original* version by Stephen Toub and Shawn Farkas. In this class they implement several random generators that seem to be cryptographically secure.

I have used the following version in my projects for random integer generation.

```
public class RandomGenerator
{
    readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider csp;

    public RandomGenerator()
    {
        csp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    }

    public int Next(int minValue, int maxExclusiveValue)
    {
        if (minValue >= maxExclusiveValue)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("minValue must be lower than maxExclusiveValue");

        long diff = (long)maxExclusiveValue - minValue;
        long upperBound = uint.MaxValue / diff * diff;

        uint ui;
        do
        {
            ui = GetRandomUInt();
        } while (ui >= upperBound);
        return (int)(minValue + (ui % diff));
    }

    private uint GetRandomUInt()
    {
        var randomBytes = GenerateRandomBytes(sizeof(uint));
        return BitConverter.ToUInt32(randomBytes, 0);
    }

    private byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int bytesNumber)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesNumber];
        csp.GetBytes(buffer);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure I understand what it does, because it uses functions defined elsewhere and is further complicated to be thread-safe, but once I understand it I'll consider using it.

Comment: Something to pay particular attention to is the way the loop gets rid of bias; it works out the largest range that could be moduloed without bias and then loops until it gets a number in that range. It costs to do those loops, but every time it has to is a time that just moduloing would have bias. Calculating the largest range that would work reduces how often that happens.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: @JonHanna But it is not particularly efficient when it comes to ranges that are slightly over $2^31$ for the value of diff, as the change of the while loop repeating is almost 50%. This can be avoided by asking for 5 bytes, converting those to a long and then performing the algorithm.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes but then that's less efficient in other cases, so it's swings and roundabouts.

Comment: @afonte I'd answer without the buffering implementation for random numbers - it's simply spurious for this question. Also note that `GetRandomUInt` depends on the rest of the class to function.

Comment: @JonHanna You can tweak that by asking for e.g. 1 byte more than the minimum of bytes required. There are certainly ways to have less severe worse case scenarios.

Comment: @JonHanna and MaartenBodewes thank you for your wise advises. I like this topic but you certainly have much more experience than me. In order to improve my answer I implemented GetRandomUInt inside a smaller class adapted to this question. I will try to improve the algorithm in the future following your points of views. If you have a better approach for doing this please share it, it will be appreciated.

Comment: @afonte Be very careful about doing so - easy to make mistakes. I tried to find the Java code for it (SecureRandom has a nextInt(int) method that is pretty efficient, but it is too much oriented to solve the sign issues in Java (in Java all integers are signed). I see some issues with the code above, I wanted to upvote, but I guess some things need to be resolved first.

Comment: Above code is at least faulty when 0 or 1 bytes of randomness is requested. `GetRandomUInt` should probably be replaced with a non-optimized version that directly uses `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, without the rest of the implementation, the code cannot be used directly.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I added a second option using RNGCryptoServiceProvider as you suggested. Do you think I should delete the first one?

Comment: You should probably integrate the two. The first one is wrong for range sizes 1 & 2 and doesn't use the RNG directly. The new one results in biased output. You do need at least the trick with the upperbound.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I made the integration. I also decided to remove the thread safe part because it is spurious for this question as you said before. Feel free to edit my answer or to give me more advises if you see any improvements to do.

Comment: Looks OK now. It's a bit spurious to ask for a random if the range is [N, N+1) as N is the only viable option, but that's not a big issue - the code should still run.

Comment: Note: If you're using this as a drop-in replacement for Random, you'll want `minValue == maxExclusiveValue` to return `minValue`.  This incorrectly treats `maxExclusiveValue` as an inclusive value...but that's how [System.Random.Next(Int32,Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is implemented.

Answer (score 13):

There are two issues in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426420/how-can-i-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-random-integer-within-a-range/42426750#42426750).

- It does not dispose the disposable csp correctly
- When *minvalue* equals *maxvalue*, it throws an error (the standard *random* method does not)

#### [Revised code](https://github.com/scholtz/covid-sk-api/blob/main/CovidMassTesting/Helpers/RandomGenerator.cs)

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace CovidMassTesting.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Secure random generator
    ///
    /// <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426420/how-to-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-random-integer-within-a-range>
    ///
    /// </summary>
    public class RandomGenerator : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider csp;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public RandomGenerator()
        {
            csp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get random value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="minValue"></param>
        /// <param name="maxExclusiveValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int Next(int minValue, int maxExclusiveValue)
        {
            if (minValue == maxExclusiveValue)
                return minValue;

            if (minValue > maxExclusiveValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(minValue)} must be lower than {nameof(maxExclusiveValue)}");
            }

            var diff = (long)maxExclusiveValue - minValue;
            var upperBound = uint.MaxValue / diff * diff;

            uint ui;
            do
            {
                ui = GetRandomUInt();
            } while (ui >= upperBound);

            return (int)(minValue + (ui % diff));
        }

        private uint GetRandomUInt()
        {
            var randomBytes = GenerateRandomBytes(sizeof(uint));
            return BitConverter.ToUInt32(randomBytes, 0);
        }

        private byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int bytesNumber)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bytesNumber];
            csp.GetBytes(buffer);
            return buffer;
        }

        private bool _disposed;

        /// <summary>
        /// Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing"></param>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (disposing)
            {
                // Dispose managed state (managed objects).
                csp?.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

## Usage

```cs
/// <summary>
        /// Generates a random password,
        /// respecting the given strength requirements.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="opts">A valid PasswordOptions object
        /// containing the password strength requirements.</param>
        /// <returns>A random password</returns>
        public static string GenerateRandomPassword(PasswordOptions opts = null)
        {
            if (opts == null) opts = new PasswordOptions()
            {
                RequiredLength = 10,
                RequiredUniqueChars = 4,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireNonAlphanumeric = true,
                RequireUppercase = true
            };

            string[] randomChars = new[] {
                "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",    // Uppercase
                "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz",    // Lowercase
                "0123456789",                   // Digits
                "!@$?_-"                        // Non-alphanumeric
            };

            using RandomGenerator rand = new RandomGenerator();
            List<char> chars = new List<char>();

            if (opts.RequireUppercase)
                chars.Insert(rand.Next(0, chars.Count),
                    randomChars[0][rand.Next(0, randomChars[0].Length)]);

            if (opts.RequireLowercase)
                chars.Insert(rand.Next(0, chars.Count),
                    randomChars[1][rand.Next(0, randomChars[1].Length)]);

            if (opts.RequireDigit)
                chars.Insert(rand.Next(0, chars.Count),
                    randomChars[2][rand.Next(0, randomChars[2].Length)]);

            if (opts.RequireNonAlphanumeric)
                chars.Insert(rand.Next(0, chars.Count),
                    randomChars[3][rand.Next(0, randomChars[3].Length)]);

            for (int i = chars.Count; i < opts.RequiredLength
                || chars.Distinct().Count() < opts.RequiredUniqueChars; i++)
            {
                string rcs = randomChars[rand.Next(0, randomChars.Length)];
                chars.Insert(rand.Next(0, chars.Count),
                    rcs[rand.Next(0, rcs.Length)]);
            }

            return new string(chars.ToArray());
        }
```

Answer (score 12):

In .NET 6, `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` used in the previous answers is now [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0023).

For cryptographic random numbers, simply use `RandomNumberGenerator` static methods, such as:

```
var byteArray = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(24);
```

Comment: Yes, according to the link you provided, RNGCryptoService provider is indeed obsolete. But the example you gave doesn't work, it brings up the error `CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'byte[]'`. If you just want to get a random integer, use `RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(...)` - either with one `GetInt32(toMaxExclusive)` or two arguments `GetInt32(min, toMaxExclusive)`.

Comment: Is there any information about why `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is obsolete? Does it have a vulnerability or something? Is it safe to use in .NET versions before 6?

Answer (score 6):

From your code I can see, you want to get a random integer number from an interval.

There is a new cryptographic [random number generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getint32?view=net-6.0) included in .NET (since versions Core 3.0, Core 3.1, .NET 5, .NET 6, .NET 7 RC 1 and .NET Standard 2.1).

As [jws mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426420/how-can-i-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-random-integer-within-a-range/70654577#70654577), the formerly used class RNGCryptoServiceProvider is deprecated.

You can use this helper method. It can also easily replace the unsafe System.Random's .Next method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generate a secure random number
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fromInclusive">Random number interval (min, including this number)</param>
/// <param name="toExclusive">Random number interval (max, excluding this number)</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private int RandomNumber(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive)
=> System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(fromInclusive, toExclusive);
```

To simulate rolling a dice, use it like

```
var getNumber = RandomNumber(1, 7); // including 1, excluding 7 => 1 .. 6
```

If you prefer to use it "the old way" with .Next(), you can create a class like so (note that instead of a seed there are the fromInclusive and toExclusive  parameters instead):

```
public class SecureRandom
{
    private int fromInc, toExcl;
    public SecureRandom(int toExclusive = 2) => Init(0, toExclusive);
    public SecureRandom(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive) 
           => Init(fromInclusive, toExclusive);
    private void Init(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive)
    {
        fromInc = fromInclusive; toExcl = toExclusive;
    }
    
    public int Next() => RandomNumber(fromInc, toExcl);

    public static int RandomNumber(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive)
    => System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(fromInclusive, toExclusive);
}
```

**Example:**

```
// always the same interval in a loop:
var rnd = new SecureRandom(1, 7); 
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next()); // roll the dice 100 times
}

// alternative usage (without creating an instance):
Console.WriteLine(SecureRandom.RandomNumber(1, 7));
```

**Note:**

- This version doesn't require to get an instance from the cryptographic class any more - you just call it to get the next random number.
- There's also an overload of `GetInt32(...)` which takes one argument for the maximum exclusive value, which starts from the minimum value 0. If you need that, feel free to update the code and create another overloaded method for the static function `RandomNumber`.