# Algorithm to get ushort number from GUID c#

Tags: c#, uniqueidentifier

How to get an unique(most of the time) `ushort` number from `GUID`, I have tried below code but since I am converting it to ushort so it is just ignoring the LSB hexadecimal values of GUID

```
static ushort GetId() {
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            byte[] buffer = guid.ToByteArray();
            return BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
}
```

FYI: Somewhere in my code, I have a guid and I want to keep the corresponding ushort number.

Comment: `ushort` has only 65,536 possible values, how random/unique do you need it to be?

Comment: If you want a unique 16 bit value the simplest way is to use a counter, the idea that you can borrow 16 bits of uniqueness from 128 bits of uniqueness is not going to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a cryptographically secure random integer within a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426420/how-to-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-random-integer-within-a-range)

Comment: A GUID has 2^122 or 5,316,911,983,139,663,491,615,228,241,121,400,000 different possible values. An `ushort` has 65,535. See the difference? What you're asking for is impossible. Instead explain what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: **Why** do you want the `ushort` to be based on the GUID? Why not just generate a random `ushort` as per the duplicate?

Comment: This is not likely to come to a good end.  At least use uint, Guid.GetHashCode() tries to do a reasonable job of taking advantage of the bits in a guid that are unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried below code but since I am converting it to ushort so it
>   is just ignoring the LSB hexadecimal values of GUID

Yes, this is correct and for good reason, you cannot store 128 bits of data in 16 bits of data.

```
Name                    Length (bytes)  Contents
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
time_low                            4   integer giving the low 32 bits of the time
time_mid                            2   integer giving the middle 16 bits of the time
time_hi_and_version                 2   4-bit "version" in the most significant bits, followed by the high 12 bits of the time
clock_seq_hi_and_res clock_seq_low  2   1-3 bit "variant" in the most significant bits, followed by the 13-15 bit clock sequence
node                                6   the 48-bit node id
```

If you want the last 16 bits (2 bytes, 4 hex values) Just reverse the array

```
Array.Reverse(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
return BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
```

***Note*** what you are doing is very suspect, and i truly think you need to rethink your design

Comment: Does this factor in the odd (to some people) way that `ToByteArray` returns its data? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tobytearray?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

Comment: @mjwills interesting i actually didn't expect that, however the last groups should be intact (as far i could gather)