# How to get NextDouble from cryptogaphy random RandomNumberGenerator

Tags: c#, .net, random, cryptography, rngcryptoserviceprovider

I want to have a cryptographic random double,
since `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is obsolete in .NET 6
this question is not relevant [How to generate a cryptographically secure Double between 0 and 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854438/how-to-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-double-between-0-and-1)

`RandomNumberGenerator` is recommended, so does `RandomNumberGenerator` have any method like `Random.NextDouble` that will return double equals or great than 0.0 and less than 1.0 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a cryptographically secure Double between 0 and 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854438/how-to-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-double-between-0-and-1)

Comment: @SirRufo Its based on RNGCryptoServiceProvider which is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 6 and above

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

static double NextDouble()
{
    ulong nextULong = BitConverter.ToUInt64(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(sizeof(ulong)));

    return (nextULong >> 11) * (1.0 / (1ul << 53));
}
```

For example

```
double randomDobule = NextDouble();
Console.WriteLine(randomDobule);

// 0.9007393363493708
```

Comment: You can have a look at https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Random.Xoshiro256StarStarImpl.cs,245

Comment: @SirRufo this is a seed based Random and not a cryptography one

Comment: Did you see the method `NextDouble()`? Did you read the comment? The methods shows you how to transform an unsigned 64bit int into a double. It does not matter who has built that unsigned 64bit int (seed based, cryptography or magic dust random)

Comment: @SirRufo this is not needed even it may can be used because there is a RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32 method

Comment: This is a dangerous example of code as it misrepresents what it is doing by using Crypto random generator while in reality it gives only 32bits of randomness for 64bytes long value.

Comment: I agree this answer is incorrect because it fails to be full entropy, and almost certainly anyone using a cryptographic rng would expect a full-entropy double value from nextDouble. The [javadocs for the equivalent Java method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()) show how it should be done:

Comment: The main point was the randomness even if the range is not full, but you are right also.,
I have updated my answer to return to full range random.